# Is this limit almost sure, in distribution, or other?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose I have a sequence of random variables $X_i$ and a pair of scalars $a,b$ with the property that $$\lim_{i\to\infty} \Pr(a\leq X_i \leq b)\to1$$.  What is the name for this kind of limiting statement?  Could I say that "with probability one, we have $a\leq X_i \leq b$ as $i\to\infty$?"

Comment: Convergence... to what ?

Comment: Duly noted and edited accordingly, thanks

Comment: This is neither of the convergences mentioned in the title. Almost sure convergence would require some a.s. Limit of X_i, which is not given by your condition (just consider any X_i sequence between a and b, nonrandom and with no limit). This is also not a convergence in distribution or in measure, since there are many distributions with Support in [a,b]. It just states that with a probability converging to 1 your r.v. take values in [a,b].